# How is NMR different from hyperfine structure?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, nuclear-magnetic-resonance, hyperfine-structure

Essentially I've confused myself by trying to understand NMR (nuclear magnetic resonance) as the transition between hyperfine levels and I seem to encounter a contradiction. I'll describe my understanding of hyperfine structure, then my understanding of NMR, then how they contradict each other. Hopefully somebody can tell me what conceptual mistake I'm making.

The hyperfine structure of hydrogen is shown here:

https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Hydrogen-hyperfine-structure-A-hydrogen-maser-oscillates-on-the-first-order-magnetic_fig1_2165356

In a weak magnetic field (the left side of the plot), there are two energy levels, determined by whether the spins of the proton and the electron are aligned (so total spin = 1) or anti-aligned (so total spin=0).
In a strong magnetic field, there are four energy levels, that can be characterized by "uncoupled" proton and electron spins - the bigger splitting (splitting between 1/2 vs 3/4) represents different electron spins, and the smaller splittings (1 vs 2) represents different proton spins.

The smaller splitting remains roughly constant with magnetic field, which I interpret to mean something like "the magnetic field experienced by the proton is dominated by the electron." Back of the envelope calculation suggests the electron makes a magnetic field of ~100T that is experienced by the proton. So it seems that if you were going to do "nuclear magnetic resonance," you would mostly be flipping the spin of the proton with respect to the electron's spin - and the frequency would be roughly constant with applied magnetic field.

But when I learn about nuclear magnetic resonance on its own, it's explained using diagrams like this:

https://www.researchgate.net/figure/NMR-energy-levels-for-a-hydrogen-nuclei-proton_fig14_29488237

Which seem to treat the proton in the applied magnetic field alone, ignoring (probably for some good reason I'm not understanding) the effect of the electrons around the proton. The wikipedia also clearly states https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_magnetic_resonance

"the resonant frequency of a particular sample substance is usually directly proportional to the strength of the applied magnetic field"
Except that many sources clarify that in NMR the "diamagnetism" of the electrons does a very small perturbation to this model, which is usually a few ppm.

So which is right? Is the magnetic field experienced by the proton in Hydrogen dominated by the electron, or by the external magnetic field? Is the NMR frequency roughly constant with the magnetic field, or is it linear with the magnetic field? I suspect both pictures are somehow correct in different contexts. What am I missing here?